# Zabbix server is not running: the information displayed may not be current

Tags: zabbix

So all of a sudden, after a week of using it, I get an error message on my `zabbix server` gui (http://localhost/zabbix/.)

The error says: `Zabbix server is not running: the information displayed may not be current.`

Any idea why is this happening ll of a sudden and out of the blue? I restarted the machine - which should automatically restore the `zabbix server` upon startup - but it's still not running.

I also researched for a startup or restart command but true to form with `zabbix` helpful, clear documentation is non-existent.

EDIT:

Some more info:

`MySQL` is running normally. I'm able to `select`, `insert into`, whatever I want.

Doing `/etc/init.d/zabbix-server status` results in  `* zabbix_server is not running`

The last entry in `zabbix_server.log` is `Zabbix Server stopped. Zabbix 2.2.9 (revision 52686).`

Doing `sudo /etc/init.d/zabbix-server start` results in  `* Starting Zabbix server zabbix_server` but the status is still `not running` and the log file doesn't have any new entries.

Answer (score 15):

just get into the zabbix.conf.php

```
   >$sudo vim /etc/zabbix/web/zabbix.conf.php
   >$ZBX_SERVER      = '**your zabbix ip address or DNS name**';
   >$ZBX_SERVER_PORT = '10051';
   >$ZBX_SERVER_NAME = '**your zabbix hostname**';
```

just change the **ip address** you can resolve the error

**Zabbix server is not running: the information displayed may not be current**

After that restart the zabbix server

```
 >$sudo service zabbix-server restart
```

To verify go to Dashboard Administration -> queue there you see data

i resolved my error like this works fine for me.

Answer (score 4):

To solve the problem zabbix server is not running you have to :

First - Check that all of the database parameters in zabbix.conf.php ( /etc/zabbix/web/zabbix.conf.php) and zabbix_server.conf ( /etc/zabbix/zabbix_server.conf) to be the same. Including:
• DBHost
• DBName
• DBUser
• DBPassword

Second- Change SElinux parameters:

```
#setsebool -P httpd_can_network_connect on
#setsebool -P httpd_can_connect_zabbix 1
#setsebool -P zabbix_can_network 1
```

After all, restart all services:

```
#service zabbix-server restart
#service httpd restart
```

worth a try.

Answer (score 2):

Edit this file: `sudo nano /etc/default/zabbix-server`

Adjust the `START` property to `yes`:

```
START=yes
```

Then try to run Zabbix again: `sudo service zabbix-server start`

Answer (score 2):

This may happen because of the old and new IP address
I have faced same issue which was solve by below method:

```
vim /etc/zabbix/web/zabbix.conf.php

$ZBX_SERVER = new ip address
```

then restart zabbix server

Answer (score 2):

I was using a special character in my DB password - wrapping the DBPassword option in `/etc/zabbix/zabbix_server.conf` and doing `sudo service zabbix-server restart` got me back up and running.

**Not Working**
`DBPassword=MyString?`

**Working**
`DBPassword='MyString?'`

Answer (score 2):

Solution might be this simple:

```
    sudo su 
    
    nano /etc/zabbix/zabbix-server.conf
```

> Remove "#" in front of DBPassword=YourPassword (will change from blue to grey)
>
> Ctrl x (Y to save and press enter to exit)

```
    service zabbix-server restart
```

> Now you can refresh your browser running ZABBIX. If not, you will have to do the same steps for CacheSize=32M

You do not have to change anything in /etc/zabbix/web/zabbix.conf.php (localhost is fine)

> When editing anything, remember "#" in front of line means invisible to linux.

Answer (score 2):

As Zabbix Senior Instructor and Consultant *Hernandes Martins* says in his ["Zabbix server is not running what to do?"](https://hernandesmartins.blogspot.com/2016/12/zabbix-server-is-not-running-what-to-do.html) blog post:

> This is the first step that should be checked regardless of the situation, **always view the logs**, from the moment the error message appeared in the zabbix web interface always view the log.

By following his advice I could be able to identify the cause of the issue with my Zabbix server, and then apply the solution related to the specific problem.

In my case, as I've commented in the page:

> The problem in my server was of "4. Resource Allocation Issues". Just like you wrote above, Zabbix was showing out of memory errors on the log when trying to start the server.
>
> After increasing the value of parameter CacheSize I tried to restart the service, but it didn't respond. So, I ended up restarting the whole machine. Fortunately, in the end it resolved the problem for good.

So, take a look at the log with command `tail -f /var/log/zabbix/zabbix_server.log` on the terminal/prompt, watch for any errors, and tackle the problem according to what it makes sense for your particular case.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the problem was that I created a `Database monitoring` `Item` programmatically and it triggered a bug that caused the server to shutdown.

Once I deleted the item the server came back up, and creating subsequent `Items` didn't kill it.

The deadly `Item` had a `value_type` of `Numeric unsigned`, -1 programmatically, while the newly created `Items` have a `value_type` of `float`, which is 0 programmatically.

The whole thing has a voodoo element to it but it did solve my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe is configuration issue

```
nano /etc/zabbix/zabbix_server.conf

DBHost=localhost

DBName=zabbix_db

DBUser=zabbix_user

DBPassword=XXXXXXX
```

works for me on Zabbix 3.0 Centos 7

Answer (score 0):

The `zabbix-server` daemon doesn't seem to like passwords with special characters in them. Unsure whether quotes would work in the configuration I just removed special characters from the database password, updated the configuration files and restarted the daemon.

Configuration parsing errors don't show up in logs for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

Install **nmap** (( # yum/apt-get install nmap ))tool and check to find out which port the zabbix is listenning to?(( # nmap -sT -p1-65535 localhost )) **10050 or 10051?**
The result should be somthing like this:

```
Starting Nmap 6.40 ( http://nmap.org ) at 2016-11-01 22:54 IRST
Nmap scan report for localhost (127.0.0.1)
Host is up (0.00032s latency).
Other addresses for localhost (not scanned): 127.0.0.1
Not shown: 65530 closed ports
PORT      STATE SERVICE
22/tcp    open  ssh
25/tcp    open  smtp
80/tcp    open  http
3306/tcp  open  mysql
10050/tcp open  unknown    <--- In my case this is it
```

Then open **/etc/zabbix/web/zabbix.conf.php** and check the line starting with: **$ZBX_SERVER_PORT** , it's value should be the same number you saw in the nmap scan result. Change it and restart zabbix-server and httpd and you are good to go!

Answer (score 0):

There maybe IP address conflict, try host 'Zabbix server'

Answer (score 0):

I was in the same trouble.
For my case, that was a conflict between /etc/zabbix/zabbix_agentd.conf and zabbix_server.conf parameters.
I adjusted

```
"DBHost=localhost", 
"DBName=zabbix",
"DBUser=zabbix",
"DBPassword=******", 
"DebugLevel=3"
"ListenPort".
```

If you run the default installation, you should keep ListenPort=10051 for the server and 10050 for the agent.

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

On RHEL/CentOS/OEL 6

- Check that the firewall is allowing connection to Zabbix Server port which is 10051, as a user with root priv:

  ## vi /etc/sysconfig/iptables

and add the following lines

```
-A INPUT -m state --state NEW -m tcp -p tcp --dport 10051 -j ACCEPT
```

restart iptables

```
# service iptables restart
```

If you have disabled IPV6, you need to also edit the hosts file and remove IPV6 line for "localhost"

```
# vi /etc/hosts
```

remove or comment out "#" the ipv6 line for localhost

```
::1                   localhost6.localdomain6   localhost6
```

restart the zabbix-server and check if the error message is gone.

Answer (score 0):

In my case it happens when introducing host with templates, graphs,trigger etc, the server falls.
The problem was that by default the cache is at 128k and you have to change it.

```
sudo nano /etc/zabbix/zabbix-server.conf
```

Uncheck # Sizecache and add 32M for example.

```
Cachesize=32M
```

restart service and voila!! server working

```
service zabbix-server start
```

Answer (score 0):

My problem was caused by having external ip in $ZBX_SERVER setting.

I changed it to localhost instead so that ip was resolved internally,

> $sudo nano /etc/zabbix/web/zabbix.conf.php

Changed

> $ZBX_SERVER      = 'external ip was written here';

to

> $ZBX_SERVER      = 'localhost';

then

> $sudo service zabbix-server restart

*Zabbix 3.4 on Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS*

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue.

I forgotten selinux conf, not all is ok:

```
setsebool -P httpd_can_connect_zabbix on
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, this occurred because the password in the server config file was commented out.

Open the server config file:  # sudo vim /etc/zabbix/zabbix-server.conf

Scroll down to db user and below there will be the password with a # commenting out.  Remove the hash and insert your DB password.

Answer (score 0):

In my case i had to disable Linux SE

```
[root@webserverlocaldomain /]# setenforce 0
```

Disable Firewall

```
[root@webserverlocaldomain /]# systemctl stop firewalld
```

Edit config file uncommenting#

```
[root@webserverlocaldomain /]# vi /etc/zabbix/zabbix_server.conf

 ListenPort=10051
 DBHost=localhost
 DBPassword=password
```

Then restart the services

```
[root@webserverlocaldomain /]# systemctl restart zabbix-server zabbix-agent httpd
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#getsebool -a
//httpd_can_network_connect off
#setsebool httpd_can_network_connect on
#getsebool httpd_can_network_connect
#service zabbix-server restart
```

Comment: I've removed the single Non English comment from your answer. Please note that Stack Overflow is an English only site. Feel free to update your answer with a English translation of that comment.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While this code may solve the problem the answer would be a lot better with an explanation on how/why it does.  Remember that your answer is not just for the user that asked the question but also for all the other people that find it.

Answer (score 0):

in my case after installing zabbix from sources (removed zabbix 4.0 because upgrading to 4.2 wasn't possible via apt on a Raspbian GNU/Linux 9.4 stretch) it loaded the config from `/usr/local/etc/zabbix_server.conf` instead from `/etc/zabbix/zabbix_server.conf`

After deleting `/usr/local/etc/zabbix_server.conf` and creating a symlink pointing to the correct config file in `/etc/zabbix/zabbix_server.conf` it started to work

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem on Ubuntu 18.04 by **uninstalling Zabbix and reinstalling it again from scratch**.

The initial installation didn't work because I had followed old posts/guides/tutorials, even from Zabbix documentation itself, so these might probably be outdated. So, the trick was to find and follow the most updated guide to Zabbix installation from its docs.

Here are the two links I followed for uninstalling and reinstalling Zabbix:

- How to uninstall Zabbix: https://www.quora.com/How-do-I-uninstall-Zabbix-server-agent-in-Ubuntu
- How to (properly) install Zabbix: https://www.zabbix.com/download?zabbix=4.0&os_distribution=ubuntu&os_version=18.04_bionic&db=postgresql

When installing Zabbix from the link above, your choosen Zabbix Version, OS Distribution, OS Version or Database may be different from the ones I've selected, but following the instructions on this page will probably be also the right way for you to install your chosen Zabbix configuration without getting errors post installation.

Answer (score -1):

Never had the problem until it suddenly appeared once, for me, the solution was to add (uncomment) the following line in `/etc/zabbix/zabbix_server.conf`

```
 ListenIP=0.0.0.0
```

Answer (score -1):

i had similar problem and my gui reported problem with cache, i change it zabbix-server.conf to 32M and now is ok, zabbix is an intelligent tool, please if it possible check problems in gui first. I had to much hosts ... for default cache.