# Zabbix servers is running no

Tags: php, linux, zabbix

I installed Zabbix server, everything works well, but after opening up the dashboard, it shows zabbix server running Value NO. Also it the bottom of the page shows (zabbix server is running no information provided my be not current). Note: the configuration of zabbix.conf.php is as bellow:

```
<?php
// Zabbix GUI configuration file.
global $DB;

$DB['TYPE']     = 'MYSQL';
$DB['SERVER']   = 'localhost';
$DB['PORT']     = '0';
$DB['DATABASE'] = 'zabbix';
$DB['USER']     = 'zabbix';
$DB['PASSWORD'] = 'NA@2016berat';

// Schema name. Used for IBM DB2 and PostgreSQL.
$DB['SCHEMA'] = '';

$ZBX_SERVER      = 'IP address of Server';
$ZBX_SERVER_PORT = '10051';
$ZBX_SERVER_NAME = 'Zabbix Server';

$IMAGE_FORMAT_DEFAULT = IMAGE_FORMAT_PNG;
```

Comment: Well ok, so what is your question? We cannot tell you if your zabbix daemon is running. We do not have access to your system and cannot look over your shoulder...

Comment: Note that the php based frontend and the zabbix daemon are two separate things!

Comment: Thank you, I just found the solution.

Comment: So what was the solution, then?

Comment: check firewall is blocking 10050 port

Answer (score 3):

Potential reasons:

- wrong port
- wrong hostname
- [local] firewall
- SELinux

In your case, if your literal config is like this:

```
$ZBX_SERVER      = 'IP address of Server';
```

You should fix that to have the actual **IP address of the Zabbix server**.

Comment: Not if the Zabbix server is on another system or does not listen on 127.0.0.1 :)

Answer (score 0):

check the zabbix.conf.php

```
  ># vim /etc/zabbix/web/zabbix.conf.php
   >ZBX_SERVER      = '**your zabbix ip address**';
   >ZBX_SERVER_PORT = '10051';
   >ZBX_SERVER_NAME = '**your zabbix hostname**';
```

just change the ip address you can resolve the error

Zabbix server is not running: the information displayed may not be current

After that restart the zabbix server

```
># service zabbix-server restart
```

If these parameters are passed correctly

check whether the 10050 port is allowed in firewall,

Answer (score 0):

This is a different symptom of the same error as ["Zabbix server is not running: the information displayed may not be current](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31502022/1639385)".

[As I have answered in that question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31502022/1639385), this may result from installation issues, and can be solved by [first uninstalling](https://www.quora.com/How-do-I-uninstall-Zabbix-server-agent-in-Ubuntu) and then [reinstalling Zabbix again from scratch](https://www.zabbix.com/download?zabbix=4.0&os_distribution=ubuntu&os_version=18.04_bionic&db=postgresql) following the most updated version of their documentation.